# windows workflow foundation vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I've been doing allot of reading both on here and in some books and cannot decide if it is worth my while learning windows workflow foundation to go in my current vb.net and SQL server application.

I am designing a sales tracking application where by an order is processed following a complex flow. There are currently 5 different flows in which certain processes such as credit checking may or may not occur depending on the item ordered.

I need to be able to have reports so we can easily see the status of an order in the database from both the vb.net application and most probably a web based reporting tool as well.

my questions:

1. As the flow can vary so much am i best storing my own order flow in the database or will workflow be suitable?
2. can i easily write select query's in the SQL database and see what the current status of an order is? (not in the application)
3. an examples that may be a good reference point?

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the flow can vary so much am i best storing my own order flow in the database or will workflow be suitable?

I don't think your flexibility would change any using the database or WF. You're going to be hosting these workflows as web services anyway and so if you had some set of rules that decided what flow to execute, there's really no difference between loading a workflow from the database vs. starting up a web service.

One other item of interest is that you could build a workflow that made those decisions for you. In other words, you should consider building a workflow that starts up the other workflows when appropriate - this would make your business process smoother because you just call one end-point to get it all going and the workflow does what it does best, flow.

> can i easily write select query's in the SQL database and see what the current status of an order is? (not in the application)

If you leverage Windows Server AppFabric on top of WF, which I would recommend, then you can query the monitoring database for information surrounding the current state of the workflow. However, if you need business specific information the most sensible way would be to write that information to your applications database whenever it makes sense. The data you recover from the monitoring database is much more related to system administration.

> an examples that may be a good reference point?

There are a lot of example on the web, but I would recommend visiting [Ron Jacobs blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/) and glean as much information as possible from him. He is the WF program manager and actually cares about the success of those using the product - he has a wealth of knowledge that he's shared with the community and it's something you need to study for sure before getting started.